# Absolute entropy at 0 K and residual entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

The third law of thermodynamics states that the absolute entropy of a pure crystalline substance is $0$ at $0\,\mathrm{K}$. In the analysis of chemical reactions this absolute scale is sued to calculate the entropy change.  However, it is also noted that some substances like $\text{C}{\text{O}_{2}}$ have residual entropy at $0\,\mathrm{K}$ because their structure is not perfectly crystalline.

Now my question is, given all of the above why is it that in thermodynamics tables such as in the book "*Physical Chemistry*" by Bawendi the entropy of $\text{C}{\text{O}_{2}}$ is listed as $0$ at $0\,\mathrm{K}$ when it should be some finite (albeit small) number? The same goes for other substances like $\text{H}_{2}\text{O}$ whose entropy is listed as $0$ at $0\,\mathrm{K}$ when it should be a finite number.

I understand that different tables use different reference scales and the entropy of $\text{C}\text{O}_{2}$ could be arbitrarily taken as $0$ at $0\,\mathrm{K}$. However the problem is then if the tables give the entropy of a substance relative to the entropy of the same substance at $0\,\mathrm{K}$, then the reference scale for each substance is different. This is fine but in all the example problems in the textbook mentioned above (and others) they use the entropy values listed in the table for each substance without accounting for the different reference states.

For example, if I have the reaction$$
\text{A}~+~\text{B} ~~\longrightarrow ~~ \text{AB}
\,,$$the entropy change is$$
\Delta S ~=~S_{\text{AB}} - S_{\text{A}} - S_{\text{B}}
\,,$$where $S_{\text{A}}$ is the entropy of $\text{A}$ and so on.

Now in order for this to work the entropies must be taken relative to the same reference state (like when we use heat of formation to calculate enthalpies). However in the Bawendi book they use the values listed in the tables for each substance, which are again relative to the entropy at $0\,\mathrm{K}$ **of that particular substance**. This would all be fine if the entropy at $0\,\mathrm{K}$ was indeed $0$ for all substances but it is not. Could someone please explain why a lot of book do this? or is there something that I am missing?